# Suppose that $M$ is an $L$-structure and that $t$ is a term built using variables

Tags: model-theory

Can anyone explain what is $\overline{v} = (v_{i_{1}}, . . . , v_{i_{m}})$ (the red line), and why is it notated like that? What is $i$ and what is $m$?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some author use to overline variables and parameters when they denote tuples. (Though it has become less common, this notation is very much in use in introductory textbooks.)

I think the notation is borrowed from linear algebra where sometimes vectors are overlined.

The excerpt has a typo. It writes $\bar a =(a_{i_1},\dots, a_{i_m})\in M$ while it should be $\ \in M^m$

Comment: It's not necessarily a typo. It's a common convention to write e.g. $a\in M$ when $a$ is, in fact, a tuple of elements of $M$, especially if it's a finite tuple. The rationale is that we don't necessarily want to specify what the length of the tuple is. Some people write $a\subseteq M$ in this case, but personally, I find the $\in$ less abusive. Some people write $a\in M^*$, too, but that isn't standard, either.

Comment: @tomasz It is a deprecable convention though. In fact it fails badly when $m=0$. If $m=0$ then $\bar a=\varnothing$. Then $\bar a\in M^0$ is true for any $M$. In fact $M^0=\{\varnothing\}$. It is even true if $M=\varnothing$! On the other hand $\varnothing\in\varnothing$ is clearly wrong. The case $m=0$ is far from uncommon as it comprises closed terms and formulas (sentences).

Comment: @tomasz I have never seen $a\in M^*$. I have seen $a\in M^{|a|}$ which sounds reasonable. (Usually $|a|$ denotes the length of $a$, the $m$ of the OP.)

Comment: With the possible sole exception of $M=\emptyset$, I don't see how it fails for $m=0$ any more than it fails for any other $m\neq 1$. Anyway, your or mine opinion is besides the point here.

Comment: @PrimoPetri Can we just say that $\overline{v} \in M^m$?

Comment: Yes, $\bar a\in M^m$ is perfectly fine. Not $\bar v$, because this  is a tuple of *variables*, they are syntactic objects, they do not belong the model.